# VLOOKUP not finding value

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a list of countries in column A matched with a list of GDP per capita in column B.

I also have a list of countries in column I matched with a list of immigration rates in column J.

See document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y4J1RGDQnflxn74Y7xbA0BuZC4yNXvg3kR56QrLZiW0/edit?usp=sharing

In column G I am attempting to use VLOOKUP to match the Column A and B list with immigration rates from column J. But most fields return either "N/A" or a wrong value.

My first VLOOKUP is:
`=VLOOKUP(A2,$I$2:$J$223,2)`

To see if it was a formatting issue, I have tried manually typing in the name "Afghanistan" in both columns with no luck. I have also tried copy/pasting the value from one column to another. Still no luck.

What is my issue?

Comment: You lookup list is not sorted, so add a last argument `FALSE` to your vlookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I download your sheet to Excel and use the full version of the formula as follows, it works perfectly.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$I$2:$J$223,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, the "FALSE" argument made it work also in Google Spreadsheet.